# Relation between user and posts in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a instagram like social site. Here I have made one-many relationship between user and post model ie, post's ids are getting saved in its user(author) profile and author details in the post model is hardcoded.Here the problem is, when user edit his/her profile, that change is not happening in those posts which were posted before that user's profile's update.

```
//Post model
const postSchema = new Schema({
category : {
    type: String
},
content: {
    type: String
},
caption: {
    type: String
},
tags: [{
    type: String
}],
createdAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
author: {
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
} ,

likes:[{
    type:String
}],

comments:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
}]

});

//user model
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
avatar:{
    type:String
},
bio:{
    type: String
},
followers:[
    {
        type: String 
    }
],
followings:[
    {
        type: String
    }
],
posts:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post"
}]
});
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems you have only author name in the post and it is the thing that won't change after you update author.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am saying. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can ignore the `author.name` from posts and always get it from the `user` model whose id you already have I suppose in uid.

Comment: When i only fetch the posts, then I can get the author info from user model by lookup aggregation? Is there any other strategy to do that?

Comment: You can do it at application level or use mongoose `ref`.

Comment: The it will become two way normalization which I don't want to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463227/how-to-solve-validaion-error-in-mongodb-while-using-firebase-uid.    @vibhor1997a